# Употребление слова "благодарна"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Можно ли говорить: "Я благодарна за помощь" или "Я благодарна за полученную информацию", или обязательно нужно добавлять местоимение "вам", например: "Я благодарна вам за помощь" или "Я благодарна вам за полученную информацию"?

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от того, какой оттенок требуется придать сказанному.
Если необходимо просто формально поблагодарить, возможно даже слегка приуменьшив роль того, кого благодарят, то можно сказать "Я благодарна за помощь". В данном случае вы просто констатируете, что испытываете чувство благодарности, и не так уж и важно, кому и за что. В устной речи такие слова обычно произносятся с холодным, иногда слегка надменным выражением лица, либо с короткой, сугубо формальной улыбкой и кивком головы.
Если же вы, наоборот, хотите подчеркнуть роль вашего благодетеля, то слово "вам" здесь не только уместно, но и крайне желательно. Так же как и соответствующее выражение на лице во время произнесения благодарности.

Answer (score 0):

Форма не очень употребительна для выражения благодарности. Она больше подходит для описания вашего состояния (oн мне помог, и я была ему благодарна за помощь). Распространенные способы выражения благодарности: "Спасибо (вам) за помощь!", "Благодарю (вас) за помощь!". Однако допустимо также "Я благодарна вам за помощь", и немного странно звучит в такой ситуации "Я благодарна за помощь".